# How can I use jquery in Vue with CDN?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I need to help me with this situation, I'm trying to use jquery in vue but with CDN.

I have this code

```
<script>
  var move = new Vue ({
    el: '#moving',
    data: {
      moving: [[!movingVue]]
    }
  });
</script>
```

but I don't know how to integrate jquery inside

```
  $('.owl-one').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        items:4,
        responsiveClass:true,
        dots: true,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
            "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"],
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                nav:true
            },
            600:{
                items:3,
                nav:true
            },
            800:{
                items:3,
                nav:true,
                loop:false
            },
            1000:{
                items:3,
                nav:true,
                loop:false
            },
            1500:{
                items:4,
                nav:true,
                loop:false
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me with a guide or some link to solve this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why Jquery

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel

You can use vue owl carousel

```
 

import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel'

export default {
    components: { carousel },
}
```